# invalid VariableDeclaratorId jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I am very new to JSP programming and I need to solve an error really fast for a project . Apologies if my research is insufficient .

I am getting the following error in my jsp

```
Syntax error on token "final", invalid VariableDeclaratorId
118:                                                            sanitize = sanitize.replace("[","").trim();
119:                                                            sanitize = sanitize.replace("]","").trim();
120:                                                            sanitize = sanitize.replace("\"","").trim();
121:                                                              String[] final = sanitize.split(",");
122: 
123: 
124:                                                              for(int i=0;i<final.length;i++){


An error occurred at line: 124 in the jsp file: /inc/AddClientForm.jsp
Syntax error on token "final", invalid Expression
121:                                                              String[] final = sanitize.split(",");
122: 
123: 
124:                                                              for(int i=0;i<final.length;i++){
125: 
126: 
127:
```

I am essentially splitting a string into an array and populating it on my jsp . 
I have the following imports on my jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.lang.String" %>
```

Comment: lang package is by default loaded so why you are again loading it

Comment: **Do not use scriptlets!**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to basic Java coding. `final` is a keyword in Java, you **cannot** use it as name of a variable:

```
String[] final = sanitize.split(",");
```

Change the name of the variable:

```
String[] myFinalSanitizedStrings = sanitize.split(",");
```

---

Apart of this problem, you **should not** sanitize your `String`s directly in your JSP, use a Servlet in order to do that. Still, you can prevent any undesired content by just using JSTL `<c:out>`:

```
<c:out value="${whateverStringThatCanPotentiallyGenerateAnXSSAttack}" />
```

More info:

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197)

Answer (score 0):

`final` is a reserved keyword in java

so you can not do this `String[] final = sanitize.split(",");`

change it to someother name

```
String[] final1 = sanitize.split(",");
```

check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords) for reserved keywords in java